# Does a "suicidal command" by a succubus trigger two saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, saving-throw, charmed

If a Succubus charms a humanoid with the Charm action, and then commands the humanoid to do something suicidal, the target gets to roll a saving throw.  Succeeding means they do not perform the suicidal command - it interrupts the command.

But if they fail the saving throw, they go through with the action and take the damage, but should this then result in another saving throw?

> If the target suffers any harm or receives a suicidal command, it can repeat the saving throw, ending the effect on a success.

My interpretation would be that the two are different triggers, even if they happen during the same round. The Succubus gives a suicidal command, the humanoid rolls a saving throw, fail, and then they do the action when it is their turn, taking damage and rolling again.

If not we end up with the awkward situation where falling off a 1000-foot cliff doesn't even give you a chance to save against being charmed, just because you already failed the save for the command itself.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I've edited out your secondary question, as it's a totally separate matter from your initial question. Relevant meta: [Is there a rule or guideline stating that each post should only ask a single question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/is-there-a-rule-or-guideline-stating-that-each-post-should-only-ask-a-single-que)

Comment: Related: [If a charmed creature receives a suicidal command and fails the repeated saving throw, do they commit suicide?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154822/if-a-charmed-creature-receives-a-suicidal-command-and-fails-the-repeated-saving), [What is the extent of the commands a Cambion can issue through Fiendish Charm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154807/what-is-the-extent-of-the-commands-a-cambion-can-issue-through-fiendish-charm), [Does a succubus' Charm end when it dies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156177/does-a-succubus-charm-end-when-it-dies)

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, you get to repeat the save

- When you first targetted, you roll to save against being charmed.
- Everytime you receive any harm or suicidal command, you *can* roll again to break free from the charm.

This is consistent with most effects that inflict charmed condition: if you are harmed, you get to repeat the save. I believe this is by design and fits the narration: your self-preservation kicks in and you realize you are being charmed and break free from it.

Comment: This seems to only deal with the initial saving throw for being affected by the spell, it does not directly answer the question about saving throws related to suicidal commands.
It is the second point, that mentions both harm and suicidal command as triggers for rolling again that is the issue. Can you roll twice for a suicidal command that also does harm? Are those separate triggers, or is it an either/or?
A suicidal command already implies that harm will be done, so are you just rolling for harm preemptively?

Comment: @dig6394 i think it is unarguable that you got one save upon suicidal command or receiving harm. Taking a suicidal command is not immediately harming the victim, so you only get one save. It is actually interesting if the command is delivered via harmful method (for instance, for a joke, "What a joke, go die!" via Vicious Mockery), which I would rule as two saves (for damage, and for suicidal command)

Comment: @dig6394 For your last question, I think you can see it like that: your subconsciousness is trying to filter out the command.

Answer (score 1):

If you survive the initial damage, yes.

To clarify - you get the initial save against being charmed.

The succubus saying "stab yourself" triggers another save.

The pain of the actual stabbing triggers a third save.

If the succubus actually wants you dead, they'd be best off making sure you're not alive to make that third save. "Stab yourself" will likely result in you jabbing yourself in the leg or something, because you're interpreting the command in a way that tries to minimize harm to yourself. But "slit your throat" would be a lot more deadly. (Rules as Written, there's no special rule for coup de grace like in previous editions, but most DMs would probably rule that you're unlikely to accidentally fail to give yourself life-threatening damage in that situation.)